# Why is the re executing statements sql alchemy example not working as expected?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I want to do some caching with SQL Alchemy and the best approach in my context seems to be taking advantage of do_orm_execute. I've tried a simple implementation based on the below link, but I'm hitting an error that I'm not sure how to work around.

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/session_events.html#re-executing-statements

My code:

```
def do_orm_execute(orm_execute_state):
    if not orm_execute_state.is_select:
        return
    
    global cache
    cache_key = f"{orm_execute_state.statement}-{orm_execute_state.parameters}"   
     
    if cache_key in cache:
        frozen_result = cache[cache_key]
    else:
        frozen_result = orm_execute_state.invoke_statement().freeze()
        cache[cache_key] = frozen_result    

    return loading.merge_frozen_result(
        orm_execute_state.session,
        orm_execute_state.statement,
        frozen_result,
        load=False,
    )
```

Error:

```
File "/Users/X/repos/X/X/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2782, in one_or_none
return self._iter().one_or_none() # type: ignore
File "/Users/X/repos/X/X/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2863, in _iter
result = cast("Result[_T]", result).scalars()
AttributeError: 'FrozenResult' object has no attribute 'scalars'
```

Any ideas as to what could be causing this?

An ultra minimal example that causes the same error:

```
def do_orm_execute(self, orm_execute_state):
    if orm_execute_state.is_select:           
        frozen_result = orm_execute_state.invoke_statement().freeze()
    
        return loading.merge_frozen_result(
            orm_execute_state.session,
            orm_execute_state.statement,
            frozen_result,
            load=False,
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out from looking at the source. FrozenResult is a callable, so I need to do the following:

```
        return loading.merge_frozen_result(
            orm_execute_state.session,
            orm_execute_state.statement,
            frozen_result,
            load=False,
        )()
```